# Magento 2, with Bosnian Language: bs_Latn_BA, show wrong price format. How to correct?

Tags: magento2, language, currency, format

I install Magento 2, with Bosnian Language: bs_Latn_BA and I notice that price format is wrong.

For example, if price is: 1345.67 Magento show me:
KM 1,346

Bosnian correct format is:
1.345,67 KM

thousand separator: .
decimal separator: ,
precision: 2
currency name on right side: 0.00 KM

Where I can change currency format for this language?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried injecting `Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface`? You could make a plugin to modify the rendering of price.

```
/**
     * Format price value
     *
     * @param float $amount
     * @param bool $includeContainer
     * @param int $precision
     * @param null|string|bool|int|\Magento\Framework\App\ScopeInterface $scope
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel|string|null $currency
     * @return float
     */
    public function format(
        $amount,
        $includeContainer = true,
        $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION,
        $scope = null,
        $currency = null
    );
```

Comment: I found problem, original one. On server there is new version of intl php module. ICU Data version was 50.1, old. When I upgrade to 54.1, working. probably in old ICU data there is no good definition for bs_Latn_BA